# Returning filtered dataframe after grouping by counts with a condition

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

The title is not that explanatory so it's better to describe it.
I have a dataframe like this one with 5 columns. The first is an Id the other are attributes. Lke the one displayed below:

```
data = {'id':[5748, 9090, 3627, ....., 9090], 
    'Attibute1':[val11, val12, val13, .....,val1400000],
    'Attibute2':[val21, val22, val23, .....,val2400000],
    'Attibute3':[val31, val32, val33, .....,val3400000],
    'Attibute4':[val41, val42, val43, .....,val4400000],
    'Attibute5':[val51, val52, val53, .....,val5400000]} 

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I don't care about the values of the attributes. I just put such names in order to indicate the length of the dataframe.
What I am doing is:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['Attibute1','Attibute2','Attibute3'])['id'].count().reset_index(name='counts').sort_values(by='counts', ascending=True)
```

So actually I am getting a new dataframe containing as columns 'Attibute1','Attibute2','Attibute3' and finally a 'counts' column.
Then I am filtering this dataframe by the counts value e.g. let's say I want to keep only when counts are greater than 15. I am perforimg this by running:

```
df2 = df2[df2['counts'] >= 15]
```

**What I want to actually do:**
I want to return a filtered initial dataframe, in our case **df**, filtered by the applied groupby and the count values as it is **df2**. In other words I want to expand **df2** to its original structure, as **df1** (with all the attributes), after running the count values filtering.
Is this possible ?

Comment: look into `DataFrame.Groupby.Filter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subset using a mask created by `transform` + `count`, which broadcasts that groups counts back to every row in the original DtaFrame.

```
gp_cols = ['Attibute1', 'Attibute2', 'Attibute3']
df = df[df.groupby(gp_cols)['id'].transform('count').ge(15)]
```

Comment: This one throws 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'tranform'